# Perl: How to get filename when using <> construct?

Tags: perl

Perl offers this very nice feature:

```
while ( <> )
{
    # do something
}
```

...which allows the script to be used as `script.pl <filename>` as well as `cat <filename> | script.pl`.

Now, is there a way to determine if the script has been called in the former way, and if yes, what the filename was?

I know I knew this once, and I know I even used the construct, but I cannot remember where / how. And it proved very hard to search the 'net for this ("perl stdin filename"? No...).

Help, please?

Comment: can you do it by checking @ARGV?

Comment: Sorry for the former / latter, which seems to have caused some confusion.

Comment: You can find most things in the documentation. `perldoc perlvar` contains information about `$ARGV`, for example.

Comment: @TLP: Of course this can be found in the documentation; I never doubted that. Just like the answer to virtually *any* question on SO. Don't think I didn't give `perldoc` a try. It is just that my choice of search keywords was severely limited, and `perldoc`'s selection of topics is both massive and... let's say, not the best example for intuitivity.

Comment: @DevSolar I know, it does take some getting used to. The ones I use most are perlop (operators), perlvar (predefined variables) and perlfunc (core functions). There are also tutorials with *tut endings, such as perlretut (regex), perlopentut. Something you might find interesting is this: `perldoc -v '$ARGV'` (single quotes on *nix, double for windows). It wouldn't help you in this case, but it's nice nonetheless.

Comment: perl -pi would  be even shorter:
for i in {1..10}; do echo $i>>file-$i.txt ; done ;
; perl -pi -e 's|^(.*)$|$1\t$ARGV|g' *.txt ; 
; cat file*.txt ;

Comment: @YordanGeorgiev: I beg your pardon?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The variable [`$ARGV`](http://p3rl.org/var#%24ARGV) holds the current file being processed.

```
$ echo hello1 > file1
$ echo hello2 > file2
$ echo hello3 > file3
$ perl -e 'while(<>){s/^/$ARGV:/; print;}' file*
file1:hello1
file2:hello2
file3:hello3
```

Comment: @Quentin: still, it's the only part of the question that is actually possible.

Comment: "which allows the script to be used as `script.pl filename`"... "Now, is there a way to determine if the script has been called in the former way" => former way => `script.pl filename`

Comment: ...but it is the correct answer, as a quick test proved. A second test showed that `$ARGV` contains `-` if fed by a pipe.

Comment: @DevSolar : That's true as long as there are no other command-line arguments.

Comment: @DevSolar `-` is shorthand for STDIN. Perl will either open the ARGV file handle for each argument, or `-` when the diamond operator `<>` is used.

Answer (score 6):

The [I/O Operators section of `perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) is very informative about this.

Essentially, the first time `<>` is executed, `-` is added to `@ARGV` if it started out empty. Opening `-` has the effect of cloning the `STDIN` file handle, and the variable `$ARGV` is set to the current element of `@ARGV` as it is processed.

Here's the full clip.

> The null filehandle "<>" is special: it can be used to emulate the
>      behavior of sed and awk, and any other Unix filter program that takes a
>      list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of
>      them. Input from "<>" comes either from standard input, or from each
>      file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time
>      "<>" is evaluated, the @ARGV array is checked, and if it is empty,
>      $ARGV[0] is set to "-", which when opened gives you standard input. The
>      @ARGV array is then processed as a list of filenames. The loop
>
> ```
>    while (<>) {
>        ...                     # code for each line
>    }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following Perl-like pseudo code:
>
> ```
>    unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
>    while ($ARGV = shift) {
>        open(ARGV, $ARGV);
>        while (<ARGV>) {
>            ...         # code for each line
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> except that it isn't so cumbersome to say, and will actually work. It
>      really does shift the @ARGV array and put the current filename into the
>      $ARGV variable. It also uses filehandle *ARGV* internally. "<>" is just
>      a synonym for "<ARGV>", which is magical. (The pseudo code above doesn't
>      work because it treats "<ARGV>" as non-magical.)

Answer (score 5):

If you care to know about when `<>` switches to a new file (e.g. in my case - I wanted to record the new filename and line number), then the [eof() function documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) offers a trick:

```
# reset line numbering on each input file
while (<>) {
    next if /^\s*#/;  # skip comments
    print "$.\t$_";
} continue {
    close ARGV if eof;  # Not eof()!
}
```

Comment: Nice! Not really on-topic, but nice to know nevertheless.